# Post method in $window.unload never called on change url, closing the tab, but ran on closing the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

My unlock method never gets called on changing URL. Closing the browser executes the method. Closing the tab does not execute the method... I draw this conclusion since no post is received at the server-side (from examining the console).

```
/* Callback function that unlocks the current time report when leaving the angular app */
    $window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($scope.reportData != undefined && $scope.reportData.superId != undefined && !archive) {
            $http.post(Settings.timereportBaseURLhttp + 'monthlyreport/' + $routeParams.office + '/current/' + $routeParams.tmsstep + '/' + $scope.reportData.superId + '/unlock');
        }
    };
```

Comment: We need more information to help, because the basic principle does work, as shown here... http://jsfiddle.net/w5WPn/

Comment: What browsers are you seeing this issue with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, unless `$window` refers to `window`, try removing the `$`. Secondly, `event.preventDefault()` won't prevent the browser from unloading the window. In most browsers, it will just ask the user if he wants to leave the page or not. If the user chooses not to stay on the page, and the AJAX call hasn't finished yet, the browser can close it immediately, and thus, you won't receive any POST request server-side.

To achieve what I think you're trying to do, I'd ping the server every once in a while and *unlock the report* if the server hasn't received a ping within a reasonable amount of time.